# Oracle 11g: Check data before insert

Tags: triggers, insert, oracle11g, check-constraints

I have three tables, film, show and room. I want to insert new shows for a film in a given room and I thought I can do it with a trigger that ckecks if there are no time collisions with the exiting ones.

I wrote this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insert_new_show
BEFORE INSERT ON show
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   -- pragma autonomous_transaction;
   collisioni varchar(40);
   runtime INT;
   error1 EXCEPTION;
   error2 EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
   IF  :new.time < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN
      RAISE error1;
   END IF;  

   SELECT runtime INTO runtime 
     FROM film 
    WHERE title = deref(:new.di_film).title;

   SELECT film.title INTO collisioni 
     FROM show JOIN film ON deref(show.di_film).title=film.title
    WHERE DEREF(room).nome = DEREF(:NEW.room).nome 
      AND ( (:new.time < show.time AND :new.time + runtime + 10 > show.time) 
            OR (:new.time > show.time 
                 AND :new.time < show.time + runtime + 10));

   IF NOT SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
      INSERT INTO show
       SELECT to_timestamp(:NEW.orario,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
            , :NEW.max_n_spot,:NEW.costo, REF(s), NULL, REF(f)
         FROM film f, room s
        WHERE f.title=deref(:NEW.di_film).title 
          AND s.nome=deref(:NEW.room).nome;     
   ELSE
      RAISE error2; 
   END IF;

EXCEPTION 
   WHEN error1 THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20491,'Error');
   WHEN error2 THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20491,'Error');

END;
```

If I don't use the "pragma autonomous_transaction", I get a `table s%s is mutating` error. But, of course with the transaction, the trigger can't see the `:new` values.
I also thought to do the check with a CHECK CONSTRAINT, but I don't know if it works.
Can you help me to find a solution, please?

Answer (score 0):

This is the classic "use a package / procedure" situation.

You get `ORA-04091: table name is mutating, trigger/function may not see it` when you query a table in a trigger that you are currently performing a DML operation on. Oracle does not allow this in order to maintain a read-consistent view of the data There are various ways to avoid this, most of which involve trying to do something slightly funky; including as you've already noted an autonomous transaction.

However, they don't influence the root cause of the error; that is, you're doing something wrong. This error is normally indicative of one or both of two things:

- You're putting far too much logic into a trigger
- Your data-model is flawed.

The solution is to move the logic to a package or procedure, which has the added benefits of removing a layer of obfuscation and aids debugging.

I can't see how a check constraint is possible here as you would still need to know the run-time from FILM, which requires querying a second table.

#### Further reading:

- [Compound Triggers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS743) - official documentation
- [Avoid mutating table exceptions](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551198119097816936) - AskTom
- ["Fix" Oracle mutating table trigger errors](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_avoiding_mutating_table_error.htm) - dba-oracle.com (double quotes my own).

Comment: Ok, thanks very much. I'll try with a procedure.
Tnx again. Bye!